# Palettes, color coding with user defined length

Tags: r

I wonder if it is possible to produce a string of repeated colors of user-defined length to further apply it as platteles to the figure?

Let's say i want to use these colors

```
colors <- c("#A7A7A7",
 "dodgerblue",
 "firebrick",
 "forestgreen",
 "gold")
```

Do i need to use for loop to produce colors of length let's say 100?

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Ops sorry, is there other way?

Comment: why doesn't it work?

Comment: In real, i need to produce colors of length 76, is there a way? sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rep()` with the `length.out` argument to extend a vector to an arbitrary length.

```
rep(colors, length.out = 76)
```